# How do I tell that timer in " timer.stop(); " inside onBackPressed() is the same local variable I used before?

Tags: javascript, android, multithreading, variables, timer

I want my `thread/timer` to stop and exit the app if I press the Back Button.
How do I tell it that the timer in  `timer.stop();` inside `onBackPressed()` is the same local variable I used for `public void run()` ?

Code:

```
Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(4400);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{ 
                    Intent openHome = new Intent(Splash.this, main.class);
                    startActivity(openHome);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
    timer.start();
    }
        public void onBackPressed(){
            timer.stop();
        }
```

When I type this, it says `'timer' in timer.stop(); cannot be resolved.`

Comment: see the answer below,and check if it works.

Comment: Just for curiosity: Whyy do you want to wait up to 4400 milliseconds to start an activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.stop()` is deprecated and you should not use that.
A better `Splashscreen` implementation would be using `Handler-Runnable` something like the below.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
  public void run(){
    Intent openHome = new Intent(Splash.this, main.class);
    startActivity(openHome);
    finish();
  }
}

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
  super.onCreate(b);
  handler.postDelayed(runnable, 4400);
}

public void onBackPressed(){
  handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
  super.onBackPressed();
}
```